# Segregating the data in python in multiple column instead of repeating in row

Tags: python, pandas

I have data as follows:

```
Events  Days
Event1   1
Event2   2
Event3   3
Event4   3
Event1   1
Event1   2
Event5   4
Event3   4
Event4   1
```

I need following format

```
Event1  1   1   2
Event2  2   0   0
Event3  3   4   0
Event4  3   1   0
Event5  4   0   0
```

i.e unique values   and it s day count in Diffreent columns. How do i do this in python?

Comment: This is pandas I suppose?

Comment: Well, _is_ this pandas?

Comment: @COLDSPEED  Yes this pandas

Comment: Willem Van Onsem yes this is pandas , please can you help how do i start?

Comment: could other non-pandas alternatives be considered?

Comment: You have to use small caps, cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, not COLDSPEED. Also, you can type "@" and tab complete the name, otherwise the user does not get pinged. Like this, @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: that was Cyley Simon, not me :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry, my intention was to show them how to tag users, using you as an example. My mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for Counter for new columns names created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) or [`pandas.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html), but is necessary replace `NaN`s by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and last cast to `int`s:

```
g = df.groupby('Events').cumcount()
df = df.set_index(['Events',g])['Days'].unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
        0  1  2
Events         
Event1  1  1  2
Event2  2  0  0
Event3  3  4  0
Event4  3  1  0
Event5  4  0  0
```

Alternative:

```
df = pd.pivot(index=df['Events'], 
              columns=df.groupby('Events').cumcount(), 
              values=df['Days']).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)

        0  1  2
Events         
Event1  1  1  2
Event2  2  0  0
Event3  3  4  0
Event4  3  1  0
Event5  4  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers and for the common enrichment - alternative solution, to make it feasible in non-`pandas` way:

with `csv` and `collections` modules:

```
import csv, collections

with open('data.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    groups = collections.defaultdict(list)

    for r in reader:
        groups[r['Events']].append(str(r['Days']))

    max_len = len(max(groups.values(), key=len))
    for k, v in sorted(groups.items()):
        v += ['0'] * (max_len - len(v))
        print(k, '\t'.join(v), sep='\t')
```

The output:

```
Event1  1   1   2
Event2  2   0   0
Event3  3   4   0
Event4  3   1   0
Event5  4   0   0
```